# Problem refresh pages nodejs cannot /get error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-navigation, production

I have built a website and when I am on the home page and refresh it is fine but when I navigate to other pages its fine too but when I refresh on these other pages

```
Cannot GET /otherpage
```

I am using react-navigation and if I hyperlinked it I think it may not have worked otherwise either.

```
﻿require('rootpath')();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
///
///
app.use('/accounts', require('./accounts/accounts.controller'));

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
 
  app.use(express.static('build'));

 

  }
```

```
server.js
build
```

file directory

How do I go about fixing this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// Serve the static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

// An api endpoint that returns a short list of items
app.get('/api/getList', (req,res) => {
    var list = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
    res.json(list);
    console.log('Sent list of items');
});

// Handles any requests that don't match the ones above
app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
});
```

Follow **this tutorial** on further explanation: https://dev.to/nburgess/creating-a-react-app-with-react-router-and-an-express-backend-33l3